# WinRT app crashes in release build but not debug

Tags: visual-c++, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have an app that runs fine in debug but crashes when trying to launch in release. This is the exception that is thrown.

> Unhandled exception at 0x5D2F7717 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Napkin.exe:
>   0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred
>   (parameters: 0x034F6C70, 0x00000001).

Any ideas what might be the source of this problem? Thanks.

Here is more of the output window

> Unhandled exception at 0x55257717 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Napkin.exe:
>   0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred
>   (parameters: 0x02D029E0, 0x00000001). Unhandled exception at
>   0x750D2722 (combase.dll) in Napkin.exe: 0xC0000602:  A fail fast
>   exception occurred. Exception handlers will not be invoked and the
>   process will be terminated immediately.
>
> STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered Napkin.exe has triggered a
>   breakpoint. The thread 0x1b20 has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0xb50 has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0x108c has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0x16cc has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0x222c has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0x78c has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0x14a4 has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The thread 0x2164 has exited with code -1073740791
>   (0xc0000409). The program '[6392] Napkin.exe' has exited with code
>   -1073740791 (0xc0000409). Activation of the Windows Store app 'cdbbf746-1a99-4261-8bfa-9cb2934d4ac0_qddg1e943mmj2!App' failed with
>   error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application. 
>   This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted.
>   More information may be available in the Debug pane of the Output
>   window (Debug->Windows->Output)'.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace by chance? If it occurs in Xaml.dll, the question would be how it entered there.

Comment: I added an image of the call stack when the first exception occurs. Is this the "stacktrace" or is there another view? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is all MS-only code and none from your app in the stacktrace. Doesn't make things easier, of course :)

Comment: I created a new solution and migrated all my projects and libraries over...works fine now. Never figured out what the problem was. I'm going to leave this as unanswered in hopes that someone might recognize the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x000007FD389357E4 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in triagedump.dmp: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x000000F5F24ED4F0, 0x0000000000000003).
 this is from core dump I got from failed Windows Certification.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly an uninitialized variable. Debug builds will initialize them for you, but Release builds will not.

Could also be an invalid pointer dereference; Debug builds usually treat memory differently than Release builds do.

Comment: Thanks. Any tips on how to track it down?

Comment: Two things you should try: 1) check compiler warnings and/or treat them as errors - usually the compiler will tell you about uninitialized variables. 2) Break on first-chance exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E, then select your language).

Comment: I have fixed all warnings and still stuck with this crash immediately on launch. I'm not sure what else to try other than starting a new solution from scratch and adding files and components one by one. I added some more of the output above. Any other thoughts? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try using the Static Analyzer tool? It's only in Visual Studio Ultimate, though, afaik...

Comment: Unitialized variable? How Visual Studio can let you do this? There should be a build error, am I not right? Do you have any examples?

Comment: @Zbigniew an example of an uninitialized variable would be like 

`int value;` 

That may not end up with a value of 0 by default. (as opposed to `int value = 0;`)

So if you tried to use that as an index into an array for instance, it may cause a crash.

Comment: @canhazbits yes, but Visual Studio shouldn't let you do this. It will crash while building your project not in a runtime.

Comment: Maybe in newer versions, but this was definitely the case in the past. It also may depend on your build settings.